# python3. Authenticate username and password from dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, function, authentication

I created a dictionary in a function. And then I want to create another function to check and authenticate if the user is in the dictionary. But it keeps giving me an error. Any help, please. Thank you. My code is as follows:

```py
def getCreds():   

    userInfo = []
    while (True):
        name = input("what is your user name? ")
        password = input("what is your password? ")


        userInfo.append({
            "name": name,
            "password": password,
            })

        cont = input("Want to add another? (Y/N)")
        if cont == "N":
            break
        print("Administrator account list : ")        
        print(userInfo)

def old_user():
    login = input("enter login name: ")
    password = input("enter password: ")


    userInfo()
    if login in userInfo and userInfo[login] == password:
        print("successful! ")
    else:
        print("No! ")
    #return getCreds()

getCreds()  
old_user()
```

Comment: When you check `login in userInfo`, `login` is a login name (string) but `userInfo` is a list of dictionaries. In other words, `login` won't be an element in `userInfo`. Why don't you change `userInfo` into a `dict` with keys being login names and values being the password?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't want login to be an element for userInfo list. I want login and password(entered by a user) to be checked if it is existed in userInfo list

Comment: If that's the case you should be checking if `{"name": login, "password", password}` is in your `userList`, since `userList` is a list of dictionaries of that form.

Comment: Yeah that is correct. But i don't know how to do that.

Comment: It's not pretty but you can just do `if {"name":login, "password": password} in userInfo:`.

Comment: yeah i tired. it doesnt check if the user is listed in the dictionary. if you run the following, it doesnt check the first function.